# How to color code my samples in Rtsne plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I constructed a tSNE plot from Rtsne package. Below is the code

```
library(Rtsne)
library(ggplot2)

dtm<-read.table(args[1],sep=",",header=T,row.names=1)
dtm_t<-t(dtm)

chr_tsne_model<-Rtsne(dtm_t, perplexity=8, theta=0.1, num_threads=30)

d_tsne_1<-as.data.frame(chr_tsne_model$Y)
ggplot(d_tsne_1, aes(x=V1, y=V2)) + geom_point(size=2) + xlab("") + ylab("") + ggtitle("t-SNE") + theme_grey(base_size=21)
```

I had the sample names in the first row of the file while had gene names in the first column. I wanted to see intersample association in reduced dimensions. hence the dots in the plot are samples.

Now I would like to see 12 samples (out of total 25 samples) how they are associated and hence want them in red color and rest in  yellow and blue.

```
ggplot(d_tsne_1, aes(x=V1, y=V2, fill=rownames(d_tsne_1))) + geom_point(size=2) + xlab("dim1") + ylab("dim2") + ggtitle("t-SNE") + theme_grey(base_size=21) + scale_fill_manual(values=c('1'="red",'2'="red",'3'="red",'4'="red",'5'="red",'6'="red",'7'="red",'8'="red",'9'="red",'10'="red",'11'="yellow",'12'="yellow",'13'="yellow",'14'="yellow",'15'="yellow",'16'="yellow",'17'="yellow",'18'="yellow",'19'="blue",'20'="blue",'21'="blue",'22'="blue",'23'="blue",'24'="blue"))
```

I tried the above modification but to no avail.

The data looks like this:

```
Genes   Sam_1   Sam_2_PD   Sam_3_PD   Sam_4   Sam_5
ENSG001   1.005   1.325   2.005   3.562   0.004   4.005
ENSG002   1.023   2.355   2.005   3.666   1.004   4.005
.
.
2500 rows, 25 col
```

The dots in Rtsne plot represents columns (Sam_1,Sam_2_PD etc)

PS : I noticed that `chr_tsne_model$Y` has lost the sample names from `dtm_t` so do they retain the sample order ??

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: Yes, `Rtsne()` drops the names in `$Y` but the order of your samples are retained.

Longer answer:

I don't have your data, so I'll illustrate some things with the iris dataset.

Let's suppose I have some experiment:

```
experiment <- iris[!duplicated(iris[,1:4]),]
```

I probably want to seperate my actual data, versus metadata (at least it's common in my work)

```
metadata <- data.frame(sample_id = rownames(experiment),
                       colour = experiment$Species)
data <- as.matrix(experiment[,1:4])
```

For the ggplot part, I would advise you to store your color-coding in a column of a dataframe instead of manually specifying every datapoint inside `scale_colour_manual()`, like I did with `colour = experiment$Species`.

Now for the tSNE part, indeed your sample names are dropped but the order is retained. I would also recommend setting a seed before performing tSNEs to make them more reproducible, as the outcome of a tSNE depends on a random initialisation of the data.

```
set.seed(1)
tsne <- Rtsne(data)
```

Before plotting, we gather all relevant data in a single dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[,1],
                 y = tsne$Y[,2],
                 colour = metadata$colour)
```

And plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = colour)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Now personally, I would take away the axis ticks, axis texts and panel grids since the numbers coming from a tSNE mean nothing, they are just embedding coordinates. Furthermore, you might find it easy to store the tSNE coordinates in the metadata so you could easily find them back later.

EDIT: More detailed data has been posted, so I'll show how it would work with the provided variable names

```
# Attempt to load in data
z <- "Genes   Sam_1   Sam_2_PD   Sam_3_PD   Sam_4   Sam_5
ENSG001   1.005   1.325   2.005   3.562   0.004   4.005
ENSG002   1.023   2.355   2.005   3.666   1.004   4.005"
# Removing column 1 because number of column names doesn't 
# match number of data points
dtm <- read.table(text = z, header = T)[,-1]
```

Next we capture some metadata of interest, in this case: does the sample has a PD suffix or not?

```
metadata <- data.frame(
  sample_name = colnames(dtm),
  treatment = paste0(ifelse(grepl("PD", colnames(dtm)), "", "Not "), "PD")
)
```

We run the tSNE and format a data.frame for plotting

```
# Had to set perplexity to 1 because only 2 genes to work with
chr_tsne_model <- Rtsne(t(dtm), perplexity=1, theta=0.1, num_threads=30)
df <- chr_tsne_model$Y
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y")
df <- cbind(df, metadata)
```

And plot the thing:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue","yellow")) +
  # Optional
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.line = element_line(),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Which with the two rows of data looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Hello @teunbrand ....I have now added the data.... a little more details ....now what i simply want is: the samples with "PD" suffix to be in yellow and samples without that suffix to be blue....Is that possible ??.....PS: Sorry for the delayed response, was out of internet zone for family emergency :(

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your variable names and data structures